# What is the best way to parse a media url from an XML DOM in javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, xml, typescript, dom

I'm trying to write a function that pulls the url from a media:image xml element but can't seem to figure it out...

The xml looks like this:

```
<item>
    ...
    <media:content medium="image" url="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EtzurR3XUAglmOd.jpg"/>
    ...
</item>
```

and here's what I've got so far, but doesn't work...

```
  const getProperty = (node: Element, property: string) => {
    const propNode = node.querySelector(property);
    if (propNode) {
      return propNode.url ?? '';
    }
    return '';
  };
```

the `node` variable is the root xml (`item` in this case) with the media image.

Been stuck for so long..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xpath would probably work better in this case:

```
const xpath = "//item//*[local-name()='media:content']/@url";

let result = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
console.log(result.snapshotItem(0).textContent)
```

Output:

```
"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EtzurR3XUAglmOd.jpg"
```